# Cannot Run Git: IntelliJ IDEA, macOS

Tags: git, macos, intellij-idea

After installing the latest IntelliJ IDEA I have appeared a problem with git version control. Because of git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113) in my mac book pro. I didn't get next update of Mac OS, and I install the latest git version by homebrew and give it permission 777 granted. And I added new git path to IDEA settings, but IDEA said can't start it, permission denied.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-192.5728.98, built on July 23, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 725M
Cores: 4
Registry: git.explicit.commit.renames.prohibit.multiple.calls=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.plugins.hocon, org.intellij.scala
```

[image]

[image]

**EDIT -
Thank you for @JB Nizet for helping. I added 'git' to end of path and it works**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.22.0_1/bin/git
```

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong. It tries to start the program `.../bin`. It needs to start the program `.../bin/git`. You need to provide the path of the git program, including the file name: `.../bin/git`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please define "git" binary under **Preferences | Version Control | Git > Path to Git eecutable** like that:

[image: Version control in IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: This worked for me, you can just type "which git" on your terminal and you will get the exact path